# How do I get started with Mindstorms NXT 2.0?

Tags: mindstorms, programming, robotic

I need help programming a NXT 2.0 Lego Mindstorms. I want to make the robot turn, stop, go back, etc. when the color sensors see certain colors. For example when the robot sees red it stops then turns. Please help me I am new to Mindstorms and programming.

Comment: As such, this question isn't exactly a good fit for this Q&A site, as it's too generic in nature and doesn't give information on what you actually tried. The best way for you to learn is to start using the Mindstorms kit and following the instructions (LEGO did a good job with it so that children should be able to start by themselves without help). If at some point you encounter a specific issue which you can't solve by yourself, then you'll probably be able to ask a more specific question. The [FAQ](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/faq#close) explains which questions should be asked here.

Answer (score 5):

As was pointed out, this question is not specific in nature, so it's hard to give a definitive answer. If you haven't already done so, it would probably be helpful head over to Lego.com and grab get the [NXT 2.0 User Guide](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/buildinginstructions/8547/8547%20User%20Guide%20English.aspx) and perhaps begin looking through the [sample programs](http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/buildinginstructions/8527%20-/Trubot%20-%20program.aspx).

This book may also be helpful to you:

[The LEGO MINDSTORMS NXT 2.0 Discovery Book: A Beginner's Guide to Building and Programming Robots](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593272111)

If you run into specific problems as you are getting started, feel free to create a new question, and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: Books are indeed a very good starting point, I'd also recommend [The King's Treasure](http://www.amazon.com/LEGO-MINDSTORMS-NXT-2-0-Technology/dp/1430224916/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1362061201&sr=1-5). Although I've only read the previous one (Mayan Adventure) from James Kelly, I found it very educational.